# PhantomJS getJSON unable to get a response

Tags: phantomjs, getjson

I'm trying to use $.getJSON inside PhantomJS but impossible to get the result of it. Any solution? I can not simply load or includeJs directly. The page has to be called from the same domain.

So I want to open a page and do the call from there.

Here is my current code which is not working:

```
var jqueryUrl = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";

page.open("http://www.example.com/", function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
            page.includeJs(jqueryUrl, function() {
            var result = page.evaluate(function() {
                $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/someJson', function(data) {
                    return data;
                });
            });
            console.log(result);
            phantom.exit();
        });
    } else {
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) handler to check for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `page.onCallback` with a combination with `window.callPhantom` because you are making an HTTP request in phantomjs context and the result needs to be returned only after the request is done.

I haven't tested exactly this code, but it should be something like this:

```
var jqueryUrl = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";

page.open("http://www.example.com/", function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
        page.onCallback(function(data) {
            // got the data!
            console.log(data);
            phantom.exit();
        });
        page.includeJs(jqueryUrl, function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/someJson', window.callPhantom);
            });
        });
    } else {
        phantom.exit(1);
    }
});
```